# Does an alphabet with the uniform letter frequency distribution exist?

Tags: writing-systems, alphabets, frequency

A language employs some kind of alphabet for writing. One could naïvely expect that each letter bears the same amount of entropy. But in reality that is not the case. For example in English each letter has it own frequency and they are far from equal. Same is for many other languages.

Why is it that some letters are more frequent than others? I have found [a question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31164/24657) that is asking seemingly for a similar information, but the answers are concerning phonetics only, and not the actual written alphabet.

Is there any language or an alphabet, that treats each letter equally? Or nearly equally? Natural or constructed?

Comment: Languages don't necessarily employ an alphabet for writing: they can use a syllabary or logograms, as well as things similar but not identical to an alphabet, like an abjad. I suspect that in any of these systems, you won't find a languages where individual signs ("letters", however you define them) all occur with the same frequency, but the kind of frequencies they occur with are going to be very different depending on the type of system. In fact, the amount of separate signs as well as their statistics can provide an indication to guess which type of system an unknown script is using.

Comment: Why should one expect each letter to bear the same entropy? Nothing else in language has that kind of uniformity.

Comment: @ColinFine That's true, that a natural language does not normally develop strict uniformity, therefore the term naïvely is used. I'm wondering, why is that so. If we have one letter, that is the most frequent, it must be bearing very little entropy, why wouldn't a language simply purge that letter? Why keeping it instead?

Comment: I mean, from the efficiency standpoint, isn't it beneficial to have uniform letter frequency distribution, so that each letter/sign bears the same entropy and uses "the bandwith" efficiently?

Comment: @LjL Thank you for pointing that out. That is probably a vague statement (maybe even erroneous?), feel free to edit the question, if you know how to phrase it better. I'm not a linguist after all, mere interested in subject. I have done a little searching before asking and actually found that letters/signs rarely have equal frequencies, therefore there is a second sub-question, if you will - Why is that so?

Comment: @PF4Public: one important point to realise is that letters (and writing) have little to do with the fundamentals of language. Writing is a technology that (until very recently) few languages, and few speakers of those languages, had; and can be applied to the same language in very different ways. Languages hardly ever do things with letters: they do things with sounds, and the letters used may or may not be changed in consequence.

Comment: @PF4Public, to your substantive point: hardly anything in language (or in a language) is consciously created or changed. Language changes because of the exigencies of communicative needs, social drives, etc. Except in very rare cases nobody argues that a language should be this or that way because of some property of the language as a whole - in fact usually nobody argues what a language should be, they just use it.

Comment: @PF4Public: There are sometimes cases where a change affects something across a range of the language - the Great Vowel Shift, and Grimm's Law are both cases - but what reason have you for thinking that there is any process which could affect the "entropy" in the way you're talking about it?

Comment: Low entropy != dispensable. In English, the letter e is the most frequent, so we can say it has the "least entropy". Now ask yourself: will English writing become better, if we purge the letter "e"?

Comment: @jick `Wll, that dpnds! It dfinitly won't b bautiful, but it is still compltly intlligibl.` The only arguement against is that it is intelligible by those, who already use it and guess, where the _e_ is missing. Cannot tell how good will it perform, if we teach it and use instead of non-e-lacking-English. Why do you think, it will do much harm without _e_ ?

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for your revealing comments. I think we've come to a point, where I'm asking: `"Why cannot it be like this?"` I must admit, partly because of my lack of experience in linguistics, for me it would be natural to have something uniform, rather than otherwise. On the other hand you're asking me: `"Why would/should it be like this?"`. Therefore it would probably a good answer if you could kindly write something along the lines "no, it is impossible due to the nature of languages, due to the way they tend to evolve" et cetera et cetera, but more detailed :)